# check if the table exists while performing union in sql

Tags: sql

Is there a way to exclude the table that do not exists in sql union

For example,

I have a dynamic query that returns below

```
select * from table_1
union 
select * from table_2
union 
select * from table_3
union 
select * from table_4
union 
select * from table_5
union 
select * from table_6
```

Now suppose few tables do not exist, say table_1 and table_6. So the output should be as below

```
 
select * from table_2
union 
select * from table_3
union 
select * from table_4
union 
select * from table_5
```

So basically, if the table do not exist, then the table should be not considered . Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: which darabaseystem are you using, most support information schema, where you can test it before you run the code, but yu need to do it in the application or stored procedure to use dynamic sql, but it would be best to have only 1 table, which an additional 1-6 column

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _I have a dynamic query_ If you mean that you have code that generates an SQL statement, then that code can check for the existence of the database table and generate the SQL statement accordingly.

Comment: How do you know which database tables need to be in your UNION?

Comment: @Abra if you run a query where the tables don't exist you get an error, so you need to test f they are there

Comment: @Abra i asking to include so that I can include in the dynamic query. The dynamic query is huge and hence did not put here :) . So

Comment: You can fetch the list of the tables from information schema first, then build a union query, and finally execute it using EXEC

Comment: You can't use a non-existing table in your query.You have to lookup tables when you build your _dynamic_ query.

Comment: As the Captain (Strother Martin) said in the movie _Cool Hand Luke_: [what we've got here is a failure to communicate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2f-MZ2HRHQ). It appears that you didn't understand my question - because you didn't answer it. I repeat: How are you creating the SQL statement that appears in your question? Do you execute code that generates that SQL statement?

Comment: What RDBMS? I think the answer will vary based on the RDBMS in use; and if it's , SQL generated in app code, or code in a procuedre being executed dynamically.